# Highstock/Highcharts displaying points in line graph slowly

Tags: javascript, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC 5 and using dot net highcharts/highstock for displaying my data

All the data is displaying correctly but there is an issue

The issue is in line chart when i zoom from `2W` i.e. 2 weeks to `3W` i.e. 3 weeks the labels are show first then it shows the line and it happens only in 1 second approx bellow is the image which will clear my question to the readers

[image]

[image]

In the 1st image as i have said earlier the labels are shown 1st and within 1 second time the line appears on it as shown in 2nd image

Bellow are the includes

```
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/4.2.6/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/4.2.6/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/4.2.6/modules/boost.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/4.2.6/modules/boost.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/4.2.6/themes/grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Bellow is the razor syntax for chart

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                    //align: 'right', // by default
                    //verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                    x: -10,
                    y: 350,
                    //height: 25
                },

                relativeTo: 'chart'
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                    // disabled: { ... }
                }
            },
            inputBoxWidth: 160,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 60 * 6,
                text: '6h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 7,
                text: '7d'
            },
              {
                  type: 'day',
                  count: 14,
                  text: '2w'
              },
              {
                  type: 'day',
                  count: 21,
                  text: '3w'

              },
              {
                  type: 'month',
                  count: 1,
                  text: '1m'
              },
              {
                  type: 'all',
                  text: 'All'
              }]
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            height: 30,

        },
        //scrollbar: {
        //    enabled: true,
        //    barBackgroundColor: 'silver',
        //    barBorderRadius: 7,
        //    barBorderWidth: 0,
        //    buttonBackgroundColor: 'silver',
        //    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        //    buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        //    buttonBorderRadius: 7,
        //    rilfeColor: 'yellow',
        //    trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
        //    trackBorderWidth: 1,
        //    trackBorderRadius: 8,
        //    trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
        //},

        title: {
            text: 'Power vs Date & Time',
            style: {
                //color: '#FF00FF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            // categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true,
                showFull: false
            },
            alternateGridColor: '#FDFFD5',
            title: {
                text: 'Power (KW)'
            }

        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                turboThreshold: 50000
            },
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Power kW',
            data: arry_power,
        }],

    });
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried loading boost module once? Could you recreate the problem in a JSFiddle demo with exemplary data?

Comment: Yes boost.js is added already

Comment: It is added twice - please try removing one of the lines that loads the boost, so you will load that module only once.

Comment: removed one still having same problem

Comment: I cannot do much more without a live demo.